# Compare AD users from CSV to a specific OU

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, ou

I have a CSV list of usernames from all over my domain, and I'm trying to compare the list against a specific OU and send the matches to another file. I'm brand new to powershell, so after a good amount of research and comparing with other scripts I came up with this:

```
$users = Import-csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\'RSA.csv' 
$(ForEach ($user in $users) 
{
Get-AdUser -identity $user -SearchBase "ou=Sub,ou=Root,dc=My,dc=Domain,dc=Name" -Filter * 
}) |
Select-Object SamAccountName |
Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\me\Downloads\test\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When I run this I get the error "Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument 
is null or empty." If I run without the -identity $user it just pulls everything. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried printing the `$user` variable to make sure it contains something?

Comment: Yes, when I use Write-Output on $user it prints all the usernames.

Comment: I had one so I removed it, but got the same result.

Comment: Do you have a header on the column with the usernames in your csv? If so what is it named?

Comment: I do, the header is Username. At one point I had included     "| Select Username" after "Import-CSV" but that didn't change anything so I took it out.

Comment: If you did `| Select -ExpandProperty Username`, it would have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling Get-ADUser rather than giving it a string with just the user name you are passing in an object with a property called username. You could use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username` or reference the just property.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\RSA.csv' | 
    Where-Object {(!([string]::IsNullorWhiteSpace($_.UserName)))} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $_.UserName
    } |
    Select-Object SamAccountName |
    Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\me\Downloads\test\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Notes: Changed to a ForEach-Object loop for readability since it looked like you where trying to mostly use the pipeline. Also added a test to skip blank lines or usernames that are whitespace/empty string. Removed the `SearchBase` and `Filter` since you are looking up based on identity can't use those in the command. As there isn't a parameter set that allows you to use all of them. `Get-Help Get-ADUser` shows the available parameter sets.

Comment: Is the $_.UserName referencing the column header or another attribute?   I ran your edits through and got a new error, "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters". Does that imply that there is something wrong with the username list in my CSV?

Comment: @cd19 Yes it is referencing that header, when you use `Import-Csv` an array of PowerShell objects are created with properties that are the column headers.

Comment: @cd19 No, pretty sure that you can't use `Identity` and `SearchBase` at the same time. Since Identity is Unique, SearchBase doesn't matter

Comment: I had seen somewhere that that could be an issue, so I tried taking out the    Searchbase but it still can't resolve the parameter set.

Comment: @cd19 You will need to remove `-filter` as well.